# db2 query for multiple cases

Tags: sql, db2, case

I have three queries below (identical except for the first line of the WHERE clauses) that all work perfectly in my script. The first one queries orders for a customer, the 2nd for all orders assigned to a representative and the third are all orders period, across the whole company.

Again, they all work given their respective variables (all variables come from the same page) but I'm trying to fill columns on a table for all 3 cases.

Is there a way I can combine these and create one query that gives me the same values for each respective clause?

So, I would expect all 6 columns returned for one query. This is running on db2 so I don't know the best way to proceed but could I create a larger CASE based query?

```
//query on orders for this customer
SELECT
    count(*) as sales_180Cust,
    180/count(*) as velocityCust

FROM orders g
    inner join dates i
    on g.date1 = i.acyyyymmdd
WHERE g.cust = $customer
AND g.frm = $frm
AND g.cvr = $cvr
AND g.clr = $clr
AND i.aciso between current_Date - 180 DAY AND current_Date;

//orders belonging to representative
SELECT
    count(*) as sales_180Rep,
    180/count(*) as velocityRep

FROM orders g
    inner join dates i
    on g.date1 = i.acyyyymmdd
WHERE g.rep = $rep
AND g.frm = $frm
AND g.cvr = $cvr
AND g.clr = $clr
AND i.aciso between current_Date - 180 DAY AND current_Date;

//query across ALL orders
SELECT
    count(*) as sales_180Company,
    180/count(*) as velocityCompany

FROM orders g
    inner join dates i
    on g.date1 = i.acyyyymmdd
WHERE g.frm = $frm
AND g.cvr = $cvr
AND g.clr = $clr
AND i.aciso between current_Date - 180 DAY AND current_Date;
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: I can get some in here shortly

Comment: DDL too would help

Comment: Have you tired a `UNION`?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be another way to do this

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT  g.cust
    ,       g.rep
    FROM orders g
        inner join dates i
        on g.date1 = i.acyyyymmdd
    WHERE 
        g.frm = $frm
    AND g.cvr = $cvr
    AND g.clr = $clr
)
SELECT
    count(*)     as sales_180Company
,   180/count(*) as velocityCompany
,   'cust' as query
FROM CTE
WHERE cust = $customer
UNION ALL
SELECT
    count(*)     as sales_180Company
,   180/count(*) as velocityCompany
,   'rep' as query
FROM CTE
WHERE rep = $rep
UNION ALL
SELECT
    count(*)     as sales_180Company
,   180/count(*) as velocityCompany
,   'all' as query
FROM CTE
```

which returns e.g.

```
 SALES_180COMPANY VELOCITYCOMPANY QUERY
 ---------------- --------------- -----
                3              60 cust
                2              90 rep
                5              36 all
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select q1.*, q2.*, q3.*
from 
  (select count(*) as sales_180Cust,    180/count(*) as velocityCust    from table(values 1) t(i)) q1
, (select count(*) as sales_180Rep,     180/count(*) as velocityRep     from table(values 1, 2) t(i)) q2
, (select count(*) as sales_180Company, 180/count(*) as velocityCompany from table(values 1, 2, 3) t(i)) q3
```

I amended your FROM and WERE clauses to show the idea.

Comment: I believe this should work for me once I get the WHERE clauses in place. thanks!

Comment: I'm trying this, but it's not allowing the t token:

```SELECT
                q7.*
  from
            (select count(*) as sales_180Rep, 180/count(*) as velocityRep
       from gOrders g

                inner join dates i
                    on g.extd1d = i.acyyyymmdd

  (WHERE g.cstnoc = :dealer_id
                AND g.framec = :frame
                AND g.covr1c = :cover
                AND g.colr1c = :color
                AND i.ACISO between current_Date - 180 DAY AND current_Date) t(i)) q7;```

Comment: Do you use Data Studio? that can help you get you syntax correct as it underlines fragments of SQL that are not valid.

Comment: `SELECT q7.* 
from (
  select count(*) as sales_180Rep, 180/count(*) as velocityRep 
  from gOrders g 
  inner join dates i on g.extd1d = i.acyyyymmdd 
  WHERE g.cstnoc = :dealer_id AND g.framec = :frame AND g.covr1c = :cover AND g.colr1c = :color AND i.ACISO between current_Date - 180 DAY AND current_Date
) q7;`

Answer (score 0):

Lots of ways to do this. `UNION` would be an obvious way. `GROUPING SET`s is a bit more clever.

```
create table orders(date1 int, rep int, cust int,frm int, cvr int, clr int, aci int);
create table dates(acyyyymmdd int, aciso date);
create variable $frm int default 1;
create variable $cvr int default 1;
create variable $clr int default 1;
create variable $customer int default 1;
create variable $rep int default 1;
insert into orders values (1,0,0,1,1,1,1), (1,1,1,1,1,1,1), (1,2,1,1,1,1,1), (1,3,1,1,1,1,1), (1,1,2,1,1,1,1);
insert into dates values (1, current date);
```

then this

```
SELECT
    count(*)     as sales_180Company
,   180/count(*) as velocityCompany
,   g.cust
,   g.rep 
FROM orders g
    inner join dates i
    on g.date1 = i.acyyyymmdd
WHERE 
    g.frm = $frm
AND g.cvr = $cvr
AND g.clr = $clr
AND i.aciso between current_Date - 180 DAY AND current_Date
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ( (), (cust), (rep) )
HAVING (cust = $customer AND rep is null) 
OR     (cust is null AND rep = $rep)
OR     (cust is null AND rep is null)
```

gives this

```
 SALES_180COMPANY VELOCITYCOMPANY CUST REP
 ---------------- --------------- ---- ----
                5              36 NULL NULL
                3              60    1 NULL
                2              90 NULL    1
```

Comment: But this still only gives sales/velocity for one option, where I need it for all 3 (so 6 total)

Comment: No it gives you the results for all three, just in 3 separate rows. There are 6 values in those first 2 columns. The last two columns tell you which case is which

Answer (score 0):

Or this...  there are often a multitude of ways to do things in SQL

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT  g.cust
    ,       g.rep
    FROM orders g
        inner join dates i
        on g.date1 = i.acyyyymmdd
    WHERE 
        g.frm = $frm
    AND g.cvr = $cvr
    AND g.clr = $clr
) , CUST AS (
SELECT
    count(*)     as sales_180Company
,   180/count(*) as velocityCompany
FROM CTE
WHERE cust = $customer
) , REP AS (
SELECT
    count(*)     as sales_180Company
,   180/count(*) as velocityCompany
FROM CTE
WHERE rep = $rep
) , ALL AS (
SELECT
    count(*)     as sales_180Company
,   180/count(*) as velocityCompany
FROM CTE
)
SELECT * FROM CUST, REP, ALL
```

retuning

```
 SALES_180COMPANY VELOCITYCOMPANY SALES_180COMPANY VELOCITYCOMPANY SALES_180COMPANY VELOCITYCOMPANY
 ---------------- --------------- ---------------- --------------- ---------------- ---------------
                3              60                2              90                5              36
```